# matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot: More whiskers, more percentiles

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, boxplot, quantile

I would like to see more stuff on the boxplot: Maximum, 99th percentile, 95th, 85th, and the same on the other side. Is it possible?

I realize it's possible to do this oneself, by calculating those percentiles etc., and then plotting them in one dimension. But the boxplot function is convenient, it handles the axes for you, it can already calculate arbitrary percentiles (using the optional `whis` argument), and it lets you plot a bunch of variables in parallel (as at the bottom of this [example file](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pyplots/boxplot_demo.html)) -- which is handy, for instance, when using time-series data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show mean in the box plot in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777017/show-mean-in-the-box-plot-in-python)

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27222921/6151948. Does this solve your issue?

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27214537/is-it-possible-to-draw-a-matplotlib-boxplot-given-the-percentile-values-instead It may however be a duplicate of this one:
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681199/python-matplotlib-boxplot-how-to-show-percentiles-0-10-25-50-75-90-and-100  So I think you should reread [ask], especially where it says "search and research" and state exactly what you need and in how far other answers are not helping.